# How to download a dataset with .sh file?

Tags: scripts

I'm looking at [a research project on GitHub: https://github.com/msr-ds3/nyctaxi

There is a shell script file called `download_taxidata.sh`. I tried using bash on Ubuntu on windows to figure out how to view the dataset. I did `chomd +x download_taxidata.sh` then `./download_taxidata.sh`. But a error came up saying `syntax error near unexpected token newline' doctype html '`. Now I am clueless about what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with their Google account. If you try download a file using the bash script file contains:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
<Code>AccountProblem</Code>
<Message>Your Google account is not currently enabled for this operation. Please check https://console.developers.google.com/billing to see if you have a past due balance or if the credit card (or other payment mechanism) on your account is expired. You can find additional information at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/signup
</Message>
</Error>
```